# use for loop to generate table row within the same table inside markdown

Tags: markdown

I'am new to Markdown, created a table by using markdown syntax,but here my requirement is to create a table with headings only once and rows should be dynamically take the values and rows should be multiple.

here is my code:

```
{  
         "table":{  
            "headers":[  
               "Date & Time",
               "Location",
               "Status of Item"
            ],

            "rows":[  
               [  
                  counter1,
                  counter2,
                  counter3 +"\n"
               ],

            ]
         }
      }
```

here,the rows should be looped here.

Comment: What are you talking about? (language, environment)

Comment: I had a Json object here I need to show the object in table format ...so here I'am using markdown language to get this requirement.

Comment: And who parses the markdown??(environment)

Comment: I had node here json2md

Comment: "activities": [{
                               "timestamp": "xxxx",
                               "location": "xxxx",
                               "details": "xxxx"
                           }, {
                               "timestamp": "xxxx",
                               "location": "xxxx",
                               "details": "xxxx"
                           }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As youre in nodejs you can easily use javascript to modify the json:

```
 jsonobj={
  table:{  
        headers:[  
           "Date & Time",
           "Location",
           "Status of Item"
        ],
        rows:[]
    }
  };
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
jsonobj.table.rows.push([["12:30", "England","existing"]]);
}
console.log(json2md(jsonobj));
```

Basics can ne found here: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/json2md

Comment: Thanks for your reply and info Jonas

Comment: I will try it out and let you know.